# python call quit() selenium webdriver during multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-multiprocessing

First, i have codes that:

```
class Wrapper(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.crawler = self.Cralwer()
        super().__init__(target=self.crawler.start_crawling)

    def starter(self):
        self.start()

    def exit(self):
        self.terminate()

    class Cralwer:
        def __del__(self) -> None:
        try:
            self.browser.quit()
        except:
            pass

        def start_crawling(self):
            service = Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
            self.browser = Edge(service=service, options=options)

            while True:
                ~Some many crawling codes are here~
```

And make simple tkinter codes like:

```
def entry_point():
    global processor

    try:
        processor.starter()
    except AssertionError:
        processor = Wapper()
        processor.starter()


def force_close_crawling():
    global processor

    try:
        processor.exit()
    except AttributeError:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tkinter.Tk()
    processor = Wrapper()
    btn1 = tkinter.Button(app, text='run', command=entry_point)
    btn2 = tkinter.Button(app, text='terminate', command=force_close_crawling)
    btn1.pack()
    btn2.pack()

    app.mainloop()
```

When i start this code and click the buttons, Crawling and terminating works fine but except quit the driver.

I want to shut down my browser when i hit the terminate button. (excepting call `self.browser.quit()`)

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: @Wonka When i click terminate button in tkinter, crawlings are stop but browser is still remaining